# javascript won't call php script

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hey guys i'm working on a projekt for a long time and  have now a problem that i can't solve so i hope you can help me.
So I have an digital led strip that is controlled over an arduino and this arduino is controlled by an raspberry, everything works fine . I wanted to implement a webinterface to control everything over the smartphone.
So i got it going to control the leds over a php script and to make it look good i found a tamplet with an rgb wheel. After playing around with this script i can't get it working ... so I need you help

the javascript :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height:100%">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/spectrum.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/picker.css" type="text/css" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="height:100%">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <div class="container" style="height:100%">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="jumbotron">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="seiten();">Seiten</button>
            <button id="btnToggleOn" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="stufen();">Stufen</button>

          </div>
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="ColorFlash();">Colorflash</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="ColorFade();">Colorfade</button>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="ColorStrobe();">Colorstrobe</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="Strobe();">Strobe</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="height:55%">
      <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:100%">
        <!-- colorpicker element -->
        <div class="colorpicker">
          <div class="controls">
            <!--
       <div><label>R</label> <input type="text" id="rVal" /></div>
       <div><label>G</label> <input type="text" id="gVal" /></div>
       <div><label>B</label> <input type="text" id="bVal" /></div>
       -->
            <div>
              <label>HEX/</label>
              <label>RGB</label>
              <input type="text" id="rgbVal" />
              <input type="text" id="hexVal" />
            </div>
            <div class="preview"></div>
          </div>
          <canvas id="picker" var="5"></canvas>
        </div>



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var red = 0;
    var blue = 0;
    var green = 0;
    var tred = 0;
    var tblue = 0;
    var tgreen = 0;
    var mode = 0;

    function seiten() {
      mode = 0;
      red = rVal;
      blue = bVal;
      green = gVal;

      var link = '<a href="/ledabfrage.php?red=' + red + '&blue=' + blue + '&green=' + green + '&tred=' + tred + '&tblue=' + tblue + '&tgreen=' + tgreen + '&mode=' + mode + '</a>'


      document.write(link);

    }

    function stufen() {

    }

    function On() {

    }

    function ToggleOn() {

    }

    function ColorFlash() {

    }

    function ColorFade() {

    }

    function ColorStrobe() {

    }

    function Strobe() {

    }

    function SwitchMode() {

    }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and the php- file :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Unbenanntes Dokument</title>
</head>
<?php
  $red     = $_GET["red"];
  $blue = $_GET["blue"];
  $green   = $_GET["green"];
  $tred     = $_GET["tred"];
  $tblue = $_GET["tblue"];
  $tgreen   = $_GET["tgreen"];
  $mode = $_GET["mode"];

  $link = "sudo /home/pi/share/ft.py ";
  $link .= $mode;
  $link .= " " ;
  $link .= $red;
  $link .= " " ;
  $link .= $blue;
  $link .= " " ;
  $link .= $green;
  $link .= " " ;
  $link .= $tred;
  $link .= " " ;
  $link .= $tblue;
  $link .= " " ;
  $link .= $tgreen;
  $link .= " " ;
  print($link);
  $output = shell_exec($link);
?>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm a total noob in webthings like javascript and html...
So the problem is, when i call the methode : seiten();
it will do nothing ... 
do you know where the problem is ?

Comment: There is nothing in your code tat makes calls...

Comment: Check this for example:
[jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: what does " onclick="seiten();" ?

Comment: You tell us. It is your code

Comment: when you click the button "seiten" it should run "  function seiten()"

Answer (score 0):

It does not print anything because `rVal, bVal and gVal` are not defined so your function stops at the line `red = rVal`. This can be easily spotted looking at javascript logs (Ctrl-K in firefox).

You need to define `seiten` so that it takes those values as arguments :

```
function seiten(rVal, bVal, gVal) {
    mode = 0;
    red = rVal;
    blue = bVal;
    green = gVal;

    var link = '<a href="/ledabfrage.php?red=' + red + '&blue=' + blue + '&green=' + green + '&tred=' + tred + '&tblue=' + tblue + '&tgreen=' + tgreen + '&mode=' + mode + '">Follow this link</a>'

    document.write(link);
}
```

*Note:* I also corrected `link` because you forgot to close the `<a>`, and since you need to put some text (here `Follow this link`) otherwise you won't be able to click on the link.

Then you need to define the variables in your html page, so uncomment those lines :

```
<div><label>R</label> <input type="text" id="rVal" /></div>
<div><label>G</label> <input type="text" id="gVal" /></div>
<div><label>B</label> <input type="text" id="bVal" /></div>
```

Comment: thank you ! okay so it works fine,  but i get an error at the python script... it puts "  [object HTMLInputElement]" in the url and how can i call the pythonscript without the "follow this link" ?

Comment: okay i got it going without the link and tried somthing with  `var rVa = document.getElementById('rVal').value; ` but i get it only working when i reload the page

Comment: Use `window.location(link)`, it will go to the php page without asking more informations to the user, and the the php will execute the python script. *Note:* It is not a good idea to execute the script as sudo, you should simply give execution access to your script.